# jquery select current playing audio by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, audio

After some googling I found this code to select current playing audio:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('audio').addEventListener('playing',function() { myfunction(); },false);
```

But I want to add function of selecting playing audio in above code, something like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('audio').addEventListener('playing',function() { myfunction({ $(this).volume = 0.2 }); },false);
```

Actually, I want to control every sound with just one slider (input type=range).

```js
var max = 100,
  min = 0,
  step = 1,
  output = $('#output').text(max);
$("#range-slider")
  .attr({
    'max': max,
    'min': min,
    'step': step,
    'value': max
  })
  .on('input change', function() {
    output.text(this.value);
  });
  window.SetVolume = function(val)
{
    var player = document.getElementById('audi');
    console.log('Before: ' + player.volume);
    player.volume = val / 100;
    console.log('After: ' + player.volume);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
song is playing, please wait...
<audio id="audi" controls autoplay>
  <source src="http://picosong.com/cdn/fa4d593f627cc8e4a23e5608cb92945b.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<br>
<input type="range" id="range-slider" oninput="SetVolume(this.value)" onchange="SetVolume(this.value)">
<output id="output"></output>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mp3 URL wasn't working for me.  Perhaps the link expired?  Once I replaced it with a working URL, your code works.  Moving the slider adjusts the volume of the audio element.

```js
var max = 100,
  min = 0,
  step = 1,
  output = $('#output').text(max);
$("#range-slider")
  .attr({
    'max': max,
    'min': min,
    'step': step,
    'value': max
  })
  .on('input change', function() {
    output.text(this.value);
  });
  window.SetVolume = function(val)
{
    var player = document.getElementById('audi');
    console.log('Before: ' + player.volume);
    player.volume = val / 100;
    console.log('After: ' + player.volume);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
song is playing, please wait...
<audio id="audi" controls autoplay>
  <source src="https://ia802508.us.archive.org/5/items/testmp3testfile/mpthreetest.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<br>
<input type="range" id="range-slider" oninput="SetVolume(this.value)" onchange="SetVolume(this.value)">
<output id="output"></output>
```